# Servidor virtual de linux ofrece página de Laravel

Tags: apache, ubuntu, redes

Saludos, tengo que ofrecer una página hecha con Laravel en ubuntu , pero si pongo la ruta 172.17.206:8091/public/index.php no hace nada y si hago la " trampilla" de entrar por 172...:8091/resources/views/index.php para que me saque la página principal el código se está mostrando `{!! csrf_field() !!}`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces no sé que tengo que modificar tengo :
Tengo apache2:
En /etc/apache2/sites-avalibles/eduardo.conf
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tiene un enlace simbólico de :
ln -s /home/eduardo/www /var/www/sitioeduardo

Hice el a2ensite.
Si pongo en la url de mi windows la 172.... :8091 me muestra correctamente el index.HTML que está en /home/eduardo/www/index.html

Ahora con la configuración del servidor dns 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se trata de que al poner www.eduardo.com (en local con máquinas virtuales) sirva el /public/index.php, pero incluso poniendo la ruta 172... y tal ni tan siquiera eso consigo.

La versión de apache /2.4.7
La versión de php es 5.5.9

No entiendo porque no me funciona...

Comment: Tu `DocumentRoot` y `Directory` deben apuntar a `/var/www/sitioeduardo/public`, es una falla de seguridad que cualquier archivo fuera de 'public' esté publicamente visible

Comment: Si, ya lo hice, pero cuando arranco la aplicación, ya no me muestro nada

Comment: En ese caso puedes revisar el log de errores, suele estar en `/var/log/apache2/error.log`